# Vlookup tables to convert unique cell ID to multiple ingredients

Tags: excel, vlookup, uniqueidentifier

I'm wondering if somebody could help me with a problem I'm having with Excel.
I have imported a csv file with some business orders, and each row is a different order.
Within these orders, there is a cell with a certain product ID, and these are unique.
For example, BYO4/CHI would be a BYO bundle with Chicken, BYO4/CHI/GUAC would be BYO bundle with Chicken and Guacomole.
My ultimate goal is to have formulas that will read this 'Unique ID column', compare the tag with a lookup table and add the required ingredient count to a list with all possible ingredients.

An ideal flowchart would look like this:
Read unique ID cell for a particular order (say, 'BYO4/CHI')
BYO4/CHI requires 4 chicken, 3 pepper, 2 onion (somehow structured into a lookup table perhaps?)
The values next to the ingredients list for Chicken, Pepper and Onion would update accordingly (4, 3, 2)
This is repeated for every unique ID down the particular column, and a total amount of each ingredient is calculated.

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would format the lookup table to allow for multiple value updates, or if this is even possible at all!

Thanks in advance,
Benn

I have tried using lookup tables, and using this to compare unique IDs, but I haven't figured out how this could then add values to particular ingredients, and how to do multiple ingredients for one code.

Comment: Example dataset with expected output would help us to identify your troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to structure it using just VLOOKUP. But depending on how many ingredients you have it might not be practical. The other user's suggestion to include some sample data would be helpful.

[image]